# Javascript Regex not working with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have the following regex that works when used on the chrome browser:

```
file.match(/(?<=__\()(.*)(?=\))/g);
```

But it seems to throw an error when using Node on my machine:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=__\()(.*)(?=\))/: Invalid group
```

Any ideas why this might be? Also I am trying to match string that appear in groups like this:

```
__("string to match");
```

```js
const file = "__('string to be extracted');";
const strings = file.match(/(?<=__\()(.*)(?=\))/g);
console.log(strings);
```

Comment: [Latest versions of V8 have support for Lookbehind assertions.](https://v8project.blogspot.in/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features.html)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah thanks!